# Applying a baked normal map - edges too sharp

Tags: materials, node-editor, objects

After I applied a baked normal map from a high poly cube object. The low poly cube adopted the same form, but the edges are sharp, is this happening because I have no subdivisions?
Please have a look at my pictures it will give you a good idea of my problem.

[image]

Comment: your screenshot is not clear, what are you trying to show? Normal map won't change the shape of the object, it will just fake 3D where there is not

Comment: Thank you for reply. I want to copy the form of the deformed block onto the square block

Comment: so you won't be able to create real 3D with normal map (for the moment), but what you can do is beveling all the edges to give them roundness

Comment: Must i bevel the edges before i apply the normal map?

Comment: You must bevel the edges, then unwrap again, then bake again, it will work better with round edges but of course you still won't be able to see the bumps in real 3D

Comment: Thanks a lot "moonboots"